# The boxes float out of the footer

Tags: html, css, footer

Need help to fix the footer. One of the boxes fals out of the footer. All 3 should be in a line, next to each together. The Css is uploaded and html showed. However i've tried a lot of stuff but seems nothing to be working. however the right box always out of the footer, i  cloudn't figure out the problem
so please it would be great to get some help and understand exactly where i did go wrong so i can learn it
thank you :D

Css and html

```
 <%-- Footer --%>

    <div id="footer">

        <div id="footer_placement">

            <div id="left">
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div id="middel">
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div id="right">

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <%-- Footer --%>

 #footer {
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;

    background-color: #fff; 

    max-height: 50px;
}



#footer_placement {
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    max-height:50px;
}

#right {


    float: right;
    height: 50px;
    width: 298px;
    background-color:black;

}

    #right img {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;

    }

#middel {

    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    background-color:black;
}

    #middel p {

        text-align: center;
        color: #321a51;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: muli;
    }

#left {

    width: 298px;
    height: 50px;
    float:left;
    background-color:black;
}

    #left p {

        text-align: center;
        color: #321a51;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: muli;
    }
```

Comment: That's a really bad way to do this. Use inline-block display for all 3 boxes, and set a width of 33% for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `display:inline-block;` for this ids: middle - left - right

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5sLr/show/)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the `width` of the `left right and middle divs` .

They don't really add up .. try to change the `width` .. make it **smaller**

[**jsFIDDLE example**](http://jsfiddle.net/hkv6j/)

Comment: Well ,I am not down voting anyone here , honestly

Comment: Well, based on your fiddle, you added `float:left` to middle.. your explanation doesn't even match the example. Also, you do downvote people.. look at your profile. http://i.stack.imgur.com/vd7Ii.png

Comment: Did tried that. But the display: inline-block worked for me! the width is fine :)